# mysql-workbench falla al abrir una base de datos

Tags: python, bash, mysql-workbench, dependencias

Estoy tratando de abrir una base de datos con `mysql-workbench` (con Python 3.5), da error:

> /usr/share/mysql-workbench/extras/sakila_full.mwb

```sh
(mysql-workbench-bin:23825): glibmm-ERROR **: 00:53:38.675: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

Registro al inicio:

```sh
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_utils_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlite_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlite_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mysql_re_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sybase_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sybase_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_copy_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_copy_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db.mysql.sqlparser.grt.so' (cpp)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlanywhere_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlanywhere_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sybase_re_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sybase_re_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mssql_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mssql_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db.mysql.grt.so' (cpp)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mysql_fe_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mysql_fe_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/utilities.grt.so' (cpp)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/code_utils_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/code_utils_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_query_analysis_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_query_analysis_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db.mysql.parser.grt.so' (cpp)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb.model.grt.so' (cpp)
00:51:17 [WRN][            grt]: Could not load wb.model.grt.so: Could not open module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb.model.grt.so (/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb.model.grt.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9Scintilla15UTF8BytesOfLeadE)   
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db.mysql.query.grt.so' (cpp)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/table_utils_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlanywhere_re_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlanywhere_re_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/sqlide_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/sqlide_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/text_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mssql_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mssql_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_docs_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlite_re_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sqlite_re_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:17 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:17 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sql92_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sql92_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sql92_re_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_sql92_re_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_dev_utils_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_dev_utils_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mysql_migration_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mysql_migration_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_grt.py' (python)
00:51:18 [ERR][         python]: Error importing Python module /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_grt.py
Unhandled exception in Python code: 

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
NameError: SRE module mismatch
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins/wb.model.editors.wbp.so' (cpp)
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins/wb.printing.wbp.so' (cpp)
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins/wb.model.snippets.wbp.so' (cpp)
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins/db.mysql.editors.wbp.so' (cpp)
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins/db.mysql.wbp.so' (cpp)
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins/db.search.wbp.so' (cpp)
00:51:18 [DB2][            grt]: Trying to load module '<base dir>/../../lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins/db.mysql.diff.reporting.wbp.so' (cpp)
00:51:18 [DB1][      WBContext]: Initializing rdbms modules
00:51:19 [DB1][      WBContext]: Cleaning up old options
00:51:19 [DB1][component_physical]: Loaded connection list, 0 connections found.
00:51:19 [DB3][       WBModule]: Environment variables:
 SEGFAULT_USE_ALTSTACK=1
SEGFAULT_OUTPUT_NAME=/tmp/segv_output.mTP5wK
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libsqlite3.so:/lib64/libz.so.1:/$LIB/libSegFault.so
SHELL=/bin/bash
DEFAULTWORDPROCESSOR=/usr/local/bin/defaultwordprocessor
MWB_LIBRARY_DIR=/usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
DEFAULTPAINT=/usr/local/bin/defaultpaint
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=lxde-
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
MWB_PLUGIN_DIR=/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins
HISTSIZE=1000
HOSTNAME=puppypc23502
PREFIX=/usr
MWB_MODULE_DIR=/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules
_LXSESSION_PID=5177
XDG_DATA_HOME=/root/.local/share
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/root/.config
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
DESKTOP_SESSION=LXDE
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
EDITOR=nano
PWD=/root
LOGNAME=root
MWBX_JSMODULES_DIR=
DBC_DRIVER_PATH=/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench
DEFAULTSPREADSHEET=/usr/local/bin/defaultspreadsheet
DEFAULTDRAW=/usr/local/bin/defaultdraw
DEFAULTIMAGEVIEWER=/usr/local/bin/defaultimageviewer
WINDOWPATH=3
GTK2_RC_FILES=/root/.gtkrc-2.0
HOME=/root
LANG=es_AR.UTF-8
XFINANSDIR=/root/.xfinans
LS_COLORS=bd=33:cd=33
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE
RGBDEF=/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt
G_SLICE=always_malloc
GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib64/gio/modules/
DEFAULTTEXTEDITOR=/usr/local/bin/defaulttexteditor
MWB_BASE_DIR=/usr
XDG_CACHE_HOME=/root/.cache
MWB_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/mysql-workbench
DEFAULTMEDIAPLAYER=/usr/local/bin/defaultmediaplayer
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib64/python3.5
TERM=xterm
TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
G_FILENAME_ENCODING=@locale
PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib64/python3.9
USER=root
GDK_USE_XFT=1
DISPLAY=:0.0
SHLVL=6
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1
DEFAULTBROWSER=/usr/local/bin/defaultbrowser
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
OOO_FORCE_DESKTOP=gnome
MWB_BINARIES_DIR=/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench
DEFAULTIMAGEEDITOR=/usr/local/bin/defaultimageeditor
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench:/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/root/my-applications/lib:/usr/local/lib
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/runtime-root
MM_RUNASROOT=1
PROJSO=/usr/lib/libproj.so.22
QT_XFT=true
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share:/usr/local/share
GDK_BACKEND=x11
BROWSER=/usr/local/bin/defaultbrowser
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/my-applications/bin:/usr/games
DEFAULTHTMLEDITOR=/usr/local/bin/defaulthtmleditor
HISTFILESIZE=2000
SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-p1IiCmMFK8,guid=257275171e7ee421758b7a8d60c84be8
OUTPUT_CHARSET=UTF-8
OLDPWD=/root
TEXTDOMAIN=xwin
_=/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin

00:51:19 [INF][      WBContext]: System info:
    MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 8.0.25 CE build 788958 (64 bit)
    Configuration Directory: /root/.mysql/workbench
    Data Directory: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    Cairo Version: 1.16.0
    OS:  x86_64
    CPU: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3000+ (1999.995MHz) - 920.73MiB RAM
No video adapter info available
    Fips mode enabled: no

00:51:19 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.db.copy.open was not found
00:51:19 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.migration.open was not found
00:51:19 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.migration.showTypeMapEditor was not found
00:51:19 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.tools.backupConnections was not found
00:51:19 [WRN][        Command]: Plugin item wb.tools.restoreConnections was not found
00:51:19 [DB1][           home]: Creating Connections Welcome Screen
00:51:20 [DB1][       WBModule]: Reading locally installed MySQL servers
00:51:20 [DB1][       WBModule]: Found 0 installed MySQL servers
00:51:20 [DB2][      WBContext]: get_local_os_name() returned ' x86_64'
00:51:20 [WRN][       WBModule]: OS not found on supported OS list. OS string: ' x86_64'
```

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Comment: Al final de todo el `log` de error que has adjuntado en tu pregunta, se muestran 2 lineas bastante llamativas: `Found 0 installed MySQL servers` y `OS not found on supported OS list`. ¿Qué sistema Operativo utilizas y qué versión de MySQL?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Uso un fork de Slackware, PuppyLinux, exactamente `LxPupSc64`... También uso `MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 8.0.25 CE build 788958` y `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.38-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`